# Computer wakes itself few seconds after hibernation

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, hibernate, dell-optiplex

This is the situation: this is a Dell Optiplex 755, I recently upgraded it to Windows 7 64-bit, it had Windows XP SP3 previously. on XP I never had a problem hibernating the PC, now with Windows 7 64 every time I hibernate the PC it wakes it self after 5 or so seconds.

Here are the steps I already tried:

On Windows 7 I enabled the hibernation following this [steps](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html)

- In the MoBo the sleep settings are on S3
- In the Mobo I disable remote wake ups
- I have disabled the remote wake up in the NIC
- When I run the lastwake command I get unknown device or something like that
- I already disable the wake timers on Windows
- I have the latest drivers from Intel, but I just found out that in the device Manager I get a warning sign on the "Intel AMT SOL (COM3)" device saying that it failed and windows stopped the device, I reinstalled the Intel drivers but nothing changed.

The only thing that I haven't touch is Intel ME in the MoBo but I don't if that could help and what settings are correct.

Comment: Restart? Have you checked the event log for any errors that happen when it hibernates? When a crash happens, the system can have an automatic restart process. If anything is waking up the system, it would return back to windows. Sounds like a bad driver somewhere. Can you enter sleep mode without it restarting?

Comment: What i meant with restarts it's that wakes up without any user interaction, in the event log all I can see is that an unknown device waked the computer, I'll edit the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Most documents are written for laptops, and I cannot find one on Dell.com, here are some suggestions from HP...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02076993&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN#N70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out that the culprit was my Microsoft SideWinder X8 Mouse.

Comment: so I would file this under "disconnect all USB devices when troubleshooting sleep issues"

Answer (score 4):

This might help:

- right-click network icon in taskbar
- open network and sharing center
- change adapter settings
- right-click your network adapter and choose "properties"
- click the "configure" button
- click the "power management" tab
- un-check: allow this device to wake the computer

I think this should resolve your issue?

Comment: this is what I did on my third step