# Computer keeps turning on after going sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep

About a week ago my computer started to turning on just after going into sleep mode.

I've checked common settings related to this problem, such as keyboard / mouse energy settings as well as media server. They all are turned off, making sure that they aren't allowed to wake my computer.

However, even when unplugging all devices and internet, this problem still occurs. I have run `powercfg -energy` raport and when mouse is unplugged, it does not show any problems. I just don't know what is going on and why computer suddenly started to make this problem... do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: This could be a screen saver issue or a background process... Does the issue happen in safe mode?

Comment: [link1](http://superuser.com/questions/86875/why-is-windows7-waking-up-after-i-put-it-to-sleep?rq=1) , [link2](http://superuser.com/questions/113801/why-does-my-windows-computer-immediately-turn-back-on-after-sleep-hibernate?rq=1)

Comment: @DaveRook: I can't go to sleep mode while in safe mode, there is no button in menu. Golimar - I've already read these topics

Comment: I can only assume you've got a program running. Can you try MSCONFIG and remove all programs which are safe to remove and see if this alters the behavoiur. Also, see if anythying is in your Task Scheudler.

Comment: So the Windows event viewer is telling my that unkown device was the source of wake up. I checked autorun, scheduled tasks and everything is normal as it was in the past when sleep was working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have a batch file with the following commands which i run in these circumstances:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed 
powercfg -requests
powercfg -lastwake
pause
```

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` shows you which devices **can** wake up your computer.

`powercfg -requests` shows you which processes can **prevent** your computer from going to sleep. (only this one needs admin rights)

And the last one, **the most important for you**, `powercfg -lastwake` shows you the device/process which waked up your computer.

I have a process which wakes up my computer in the morning and it shows:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\WakeupOnStandBy\wosb.exe
```

Comment: 'devicequery wake_armed' show nothing. '-requests' shows that there aren't any processes preventing my pc from sleep. 'lastwake' is only showing numbers :(

Comment: Then you should still do a `powercfg -lastwake` after the next time the computer wakes up on its own. It still can be a process instead of a device.

Comment: I've edited comment right after you have posted this.

Comment: What numbers do you get with `-lastwake` ?

Comment: I've got Windows in Polish, so I'm not sure if this is correct: "Wake history count: 1; Wake history [0]; wake source count - 0"

Comment: This is directly after your problem (computer starts on its own) ?? I added my own result in my answer. According to your result the computer did not wake up on its own. (Or the `lastwake` mechanism is faulty)

Comment: Yes, it was directly after wake. There aren't any info about type and owner.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10678/discussion-between-adam-w-and-rik)

Comment: Your `Wake history count: 1;` is 1 so there is something waking your computer but is unknown (as the eventlog says :) I don't think there are any numbers/Uid's in that entry in the log, are there?

Comment: I have reinstalled Windows 7 and after that sleep mode is still not working properly. Just wasted 3 hours...

Comment: You said you disconnected **all** devices including the network cable. Then (after a clean install) the only conclusion is there is something wrong with the hardware. Only 2 possible things you can still do is check (and change) the [ACPI Sleep/Power setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode#ACPI) in the BIOS and if that doesn't work perhaps check if there is a newer BIOS-upgrade available. (At least now you have fresh clean fast install of Windows ;)

Comment: If all that fails i would just go with hibernate. Not ideal, a little bit slower starting up, but the next best thing to sleep-mode. Then definitely nothing will get your computer awake besides the power-button.

Comment: I've changed ACPI settings to S3 only mode and installed the latest BIOS. Unfortunately, problem still happens... I also checked cables inside pc chasis and everything is fine.

Comment: Source of the wake up is still unknown.

Comment: I wanted to direct you to 2 sites. [One](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/forums/windows-vista/my-pcs-wake-up-themselves-standby-hibernation-20630.html) with someone who had the same troubles. And [another](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/63567-power-options-sleep-mode-problems.html) with a lot of things you can try. His trouble was with the network adapter (wake on lan). He disabled the powersetting but that was not enough for him. You said the cable was not connected but perhaps you can rip out the network-adapter and try again. If it works you found the problem.

Comment: I did it yesterday, I mean, ripped out network adapter completely from computer but it didn't resolve my problem. There is one weird thing - hibernation is turned on but it doesn't show in Windows start menu exit options...

Comment: That happens if you have "Hybrid sleep" enabled. This is different from "Hibernate" and disables the "Hibernate option in the start-menu. Disable it in the poewersettings and you'll have the hibernate option (See also [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/20fabe93-d5fd-4da2-8f58-8bfcab96e325/hibernate-option-missing)). BTW I usually use a shortcut on my taskbar to `shutdown /h`.

Comment: Come to think of it. If you disable the "Hybrid sleep" and you put your computer to "Sleep" does it also wake up?? If not... problem solved ;) If it does wake up... go for "Hibernate". A shortcut on the taskbar is the easiest. Then you don't have to go through the menus.

Comment: Yes, it still wake up. I've put computer into diagnostic mode (option in 'msconfig') but it doesn't help neither. For me, it looks like a hardware issue. I'll try that motherboard jumpers thing later. EDIT: hibernation... it's not working too! Immediately after putting computer into hibernation it wakes up!

Comment: Wow. Never heard of that. A computer in hibernation should never be able to turn on by itself (it should be like the power is cut). If it does i also think there is a hardware problem. Perhaps the power supply or the motherboard is faulty. This is a hard one to diagnose :( I take it you did disable hybrid sleep because else "hibernation" just means another way of sleep.

Comment: Perhaps you need to disable sleep entirely. (and just keep the hibernate option on)

Comment: And you did try disconnecting the mouse and keyboard right after going to sleep-mode. (Unplug them right after giving the sleep command). (or try a different mouse) See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/219846/computer-wakes-itself-few-seconds-after-hibernation) someone with a problem with a microsoft sidewinder mouse. It still amazes me this can happen in hibernation.

Comment: Disconnecting mouse and keyboard didn't help neither.

Comment: And the other options above? Disabling "sleep" **and** "Hybrid sleep" **and** "Allow wake timer** entirely and then choosing "Hibernate" from the startmenu? (When Windows stops/starts it should give you a progress bar to see you really entered/exited hibernate-mode.)

Comment: Yes, I've done everything you said and also things mentioned on attached sites. I really appreciate your help! However, for me, it looks like a hardware issue. As I said, I'll try this motherboard jumper things later.

Comment: I checked all connections on my motherboard, took them off, then plug them again, but it didn't help. I guess it's an unsolvable problem! Anyway, thank you for taking your time to help me.